# How to change the system clock rate or OS clock rate?

Tags: linux, windows, clock, system-clock

I want to know is there any way to change Windows or Linux clock rate or the system clock rate (maybe via BIOS)? I mean accelerate or decelerate system clock!

For example every 24 hours in the computer lasts 12 hours or 36 hours in real!!!

NOTE :

Using the below batch file, I can decelerate Windows time. But I want something in a lower level! I want to change clock pace in a way that all time for all the programs and tool be slower or faster! not only Windows time!

```
@echo off

:loop

set T=%time%
timeout 1
time %T%
timeout 1

goto loop
```

Comment: Write a program that every second adjusts the system time forward a second or back a quarter of a second.

Comment: I already did it with a batch file! but I want something better! I mean in a lower level! If I write a program that every second adjusts the system time forward a second or back a quarter of a second, another program that call time API, works normally! I want to change somthing in the OS in a way that time changes for all the other program and tools too!

Comment: This is an interesting question. NTPd supports gradual slew, but normally on the order of 0.5%, not 50%. Maybe `adjtimex(2)` can be used/abused for this, along with some disabled sanity checks in the kernel source?

Comment: The system time is global, so changing it will be immediately effective in any other process that requests the current system. Either your batch file isn't changing the system time or the other processes don't change their behaviour because they're not querying the system time.

Comment: @RossRidge  I added a batch file to the question. Do you think this batch file can change clock rate for the other programs also? or it only change time of windows?!

Comment: @thatotherguy would you please explain more? I didn't understand! What is `adjtimex(2)`? Is it for Linux?

Comment: If you want to slow down or speed up other processes than that's a different question. Most processes do not base the speed they do things on the system time of day. What other processes are you trying to slow down or speed up and why?

Comment: **Why do you ask**? It is a strange thing to do.

Comment: It might be possible to modify one of the open source VM solutions to do this (to the VM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [That Other Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) you might perhaps use [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html) syscall, but you first should be sure that no NTP client daemon -which uses `adjtimex`- is running (so stop any `ntpd` or `chrony` service).

I'm not sure it would work, and it might make your system quite unstable.

A more rude possibility might be to forcibly set the [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) -or also [hwclock(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hwclock.8.html)- quite often (e.g. in some `crontab` job running every 5 minutes).

I believe it (i.e. decelerating a lot the system clock) is a strange and bad thing to do. Don't do that on a production machine (or even on some machine doing significant requests on the Web). Be prepared to perhaps break a lot of things.

Comment: "that other guy" commented it, not me! :) I even don't know what is it :) thank you.

Comment: Corrected. Sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 2):

So your CPU's clock is not actually programmable via system calls. It's actually working off of an oscillator w/ crystal.  You cannot change during booting up. This is done intentionally so that your CPU is able time regardless of your power/wifi/general system status.